# Value not changing before warning

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9

I want to change my state into 'pending' and then raise warning. But it's not working. I've tried it with Boolean field,but no use! Nothing gets write before warning. Help me.

Comment: Code, expected output and error please

Comment: what did you try for this, please explain ?

Comment: Needs more code, but I have had problems in csh where it was buffering and then not outputting the results. Running the csh script with -u (stopping the buffering) helped, but have no idea if this is your problem...

Comment: If by 'raise warning' you mean raise an exception then that is expected behaviour, because if an exception occurs while handling the request, then the database transaction is rollbacked and no changes are saved.

Comment: "it's not working" is not an acceptable problem statement.

Comment: I've a 'shift change' model. If dates btwn current date and shift change date is less than 3, the state should change to 'pending' and raise a warning.Referring the condition code only,                                                                                            
                        if diff_date < 3:
                        employee.state = 'pending'
                        raise Warning(_('Contact your manager!.'))       .I've got the state changing into 'pending' in terminal. But nothing happening in odoo.